# Mysql with join statement

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables

1) discounts

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| ID   discount_description   discount_type  |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 17   20% off                PERCENT        |
| 19   Citric                 ABSOLUTE       |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Table 2 - Products Included

```
+------+--------------+------------------+
|  ID  | discount_id  |    product_id    |
+------+--------------+------------------+
|   2  |          17  |         52238403 |
|   3  |          17  |         52238409 |
|   4  |          19  |         52238408 |
+------+--------------+------------------+
```

Table 3 - Products Excluded

```
+---------------------------------+---------------+
| ID   discount_id                |  product_id   |
+---------------------------------+---------------+
| 2    17                         |      52238411 |
| 3    17                         |      52238408 |
+---------------------------------+---------------+
```

I need the query to fetch all the discounts based on product ID's from included table and excluded table. And it should also include the rows from discounts which is not present in products included/excluded table.

Below is a sample one to fetch discounts based on products 52238408,52238403.

```
    SELECT 
        discounts.id as ID1,
        discount_products.product_id as p1,
        exclude_discount_products.product_id as p2 
    FROM discounts

    LEFT JOIN `discount_products` ON 1=1 
        AND discounts.id = discount_products.discount_id

    LEFT JOIN `exclude_discount_products` ON 1=1 
        AND discounts.id = exclude_discount_products.discount_id

    WHERE discount_products.product_id IN (52238408,52238403) 
        AND exclude_discount_products.product_id NOT IN (52238408,52238403)
```

The query is just a basic version and i am pretty sure it's incorrect. But basically i wanted to check both the tables for product ID.

I am suppose to get discount 19 as the output since products excluded has 52238408, So 17 should ignored. But it gives 17 instead. Not sure what i am missing, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a strange datamodel. So some products are explicitly excluded from a discount and others are explicitely included. This makes me wonder what about products that are neither explicitely included or excluded? Are they implicitely included or excluded then?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Basically we are passing the product ID's to check if they present in discount_products table and not present in exclude_discount_products table. If you feel the datamodel is incorrect, Could you please suggest your input.

Comment: I assume you have a product table of n products. When you have a discount including m products, then implicitely n-m products are not discounted of course. So an including table would suffice probably. If it happens often that you discount all products except a few, then you might go for an excluding table instead (when excluding m products, then n-m are implicitly included).

Comment: And you may even have both kinds of discounts, but then I'd make this two different discount tables one plus an including table, one with an excluding one. Then it would be guaranteed not to have a discount with some included products, some excluded ones and some undefined.

Comment: As to your query: Obviously you combine all excluded with all included records per `discount_id`. That gives you 2 x 2 = 4 rows for `discount_id` 17 for instance. I guess that is not desired. You should show us the expected output (in the same format as you are showing the table data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want this you didnt include the expected output.

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE discounts
    (`ID` INT, `discount_description` VARCHAR(7), `discount_type` VARCHAR(8))
;

INSERT INTO discounts
    (`ID`, `discount_description`, `discount_type`)
VALUES
    (17, '20% off', 'PERCENT'),
    (19, 'Citric', 'ABSOLUTE')
;

CREATE TABLE discount_products
    (`ID` INT, `discount_id` INT, `product_id` INT)
;

INSERT INTO discount_products
    (`ID`, `discount_id`, `product_id`)
VALUES
    (2, 17, 52238403),
    (3, 17, 52238409),
    (4, 19, 52238408)
;


CREATE TABLE exclude_discount_products
    (`ID` INT, `discount_id` INT, `product_id` INT)
;

INSERT INTO exclude_discount_products
    (`ID`, `discount_id`, `product_id`)
VALUES
    (2, 17, 52238411),
    (3, 17, 52238408)
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   discounts.id AS ID1
 , product_id AS p1
 , ( 
      # SELECT matching product_id FROM exclude_discount_products based on product_id (checks excludes)

      SELECT
        product_id
      FROM
        exclude_discount_products
      WHERE
        product_id = discount_products_NOT_IN_exclude_discount_products.product_id
    )
     AS p2
FROM ( 
  # SELECT all discount_products that dont have the same discount_id, product_id as in exclude_discount_products 
  SELECT 
     *
  FROM 
   discount_products
  WHERE (
      discount_id
    , product_id
  ) 
  NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        discount_id
      , product_id
    FROM 
      exclude_discount_products  
  )  
)
 AS 
  discount_products_NOT_IN_exclude_discount_products

INNER JOIN 
 discounts
ON
  discount_products_NOT_IN_exclude_discount_products.discount_id = discounts.id   

WHERE
 product_id IN(
    52238408
  , 52238403 
)
```

**Result**

```
   ID1        p1        p2  
------  --------  ----------
    17  52238403      (NULL)
    19  52238408    52238408
```

Comment: The answer i am expecting is  19  52238408    52238408